# Display saved Proximity Alerts on Android?

Tags: java, android, notifications, alerts, proximity

Does anyone know of a way to get/show all stored proximy alerts on Android?

What I have done:

- Get list of locations via http
- Add them to the proximity alerts via the LocationManager
- Fire a PendingIntent to a BroadCastReceiver
- Notifiy User

All works fine and alerts/notifcations display as they should

What I want to do next for debugging/testing purposes was to show all the locations/alerts that are currently stored and display them in a list.

Anyone know how to do this or point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want to do next for debugging/testing purposes was to show all the locations/alerts that are currently stored and display them in a list.

Well, you can't really do that from the SDK, other than to record them all yourself. See if `adb shell dumpsys` reports on registered proximity alerts somewhere in the pile of information it returns. I don't have any code handy that registers a proximity alert, so I don't know for certain if the information you would need is there or not.

Comment: Cheers for the response. Ill have a look around the dumpsys and see if i can find anything. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to "dumpsys location" from the ADB prompt.

Comment: Be more verbose in your answers if you want to be even remotely helpful.